# How should I apply 'for' in list with format?

Tags: python

I'm making a function merely to show all the cards of poke. Even though I have used 'for' in 'format', an error of 'name is not defined' occurred. How should I fix it?

I've tried on making it a for loop like

```
for v in values:
     for s in suits:
         ...
```

but the result was not what I wanted.

```
values = list(range(1, 11)) + list('Jack Queen King'.split())
suits = list('Diamonds Clubs Hearts Spades'.split())
deck = ['{} of {}'.format(v for v in values and s for s in suits)]

...

from pprint import pprint
pprint(deck[:12])
```

I wanted it to be like

```
[['1 of diamonds',
'1 of clubs',
'1 of hearts',
'1 of spades',
'2 of diamonds'
...]
```

but the output was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\source\repos\PythonApplication33\PythonApplication33\PythonApplication33.py", line 3, in <module>
    deck = ['{} of {}'.format(v for v in values and s for s in suits)]
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Thanks for reading until here, I would be grateful if you could give me some advice.

Comment: `['{} of {}'.format(v, s ) for v in values  for s in suits]`

Comment: Show the actual code you're running. Something I can copy and paste into a shell and run exactly, instead of having to guess.

Comment: values = list(range(1, 11)) + list('Jack Queen King'.split())
suits = list('Diamonds Clubs Hearts Spades'.split())
deck = ['{} of {}'.format(v for v in values and s for s in suits)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(deck[:12])

This is the actual code I'm running, I'm sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @JeffreyHo `string.split()` already return as a list .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
deck = [f'{v} of {s}' for v in values for s in suits]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JeffreyHo: That's a f-string, a newer way of doing essentially the same kind of string formatting you were doing, just with the names of the variables right in the string, rather than past as arguments to `str.format`. F-strings were added in Python 3.6 (see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)).

Comment: @JeffreyHo - if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. – John

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know that cuz I'm a newbie. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

`and` is a logical operator, it's not the English word 'and', what you need is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or a proper nested for loop:

```
from itertools import product

...
>>> deck = ['{} of {}'.format(v, s) for v, s in product(values, suits)]
...
>>> pprint(deck[:12])
['1 of Diamonds',
 '1 of Clubs',
 '1 of Hearts',
 '1 of Spades',
 '2 of Diamonds',
 '2 of Clubs',
 '2 of Hearts',
 '2 of Spades',
 '3 of Diamonds',
 '3 of Clubs',
 '3 of Hearts',
 '3 of Spades']
```

Nested loop:

```
...
>>> deck = ['{} of {}'.format(v, s) for v in values for s in suits]
...
>>> pprint(deck[:12])
['1 of Diamonds',
 '1 of Clubs',
 '1 of Hearts',
 '1 of Spades',
 '2 of Diamonds',
 '2 of Clubs',
 '2 of Hearts',
 '2 of Spades',
 '3 of Diamonds',
 '3 of Clubs',
 '3 of Hearts',
 '3 of Spades']
```

Comment: I've tried iteratools but the result is still "name 's' is not defined", thank you for your help. Probably my question is not clear enough...

Comment: @JeffreyHo The problem is with your use of `and`, which can be fixed by using the loop in the answer instead.

Comment: Ah, I took the 'and' as the English 'and'. I'm going to search more about 'itertools', thanks for telling me this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by properly formatting your nested `for` statements inside the comprehension:

```
values = list(range(1, 11)) + list('Jack Queen King'.split())
suits = list('Diamonds Clubs Hearts Spades'.split())
deck = ['{} of {}'.format(x, y) for x in values for y in suits]
```

Output:

```
['1 of Diamonds',
 '1 of Clubs',
 '1 of Hearts',
 '1 of Spades',
 '2 of Diamonds',
 '2 of Clubs',
 '2 of Hearts',
...
 'Queen of Clubs',
 'Queen of Hearts',
 'Queen of Spades',
 'King of Diamonds',
 'King of Clubs',
 'King of Hearts',
 'King of Spades']
```

Comment: I put 'for' inside the parenthesis of format, yours makes sense. Thank you very much.